# How to train a CNN or RNN model on own dataset in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm new to TensorFlow, and I've gone through all the tutorials that use the pretrained models for a deep neural network.

Now, I need to know how do I train my CNN / RNN model on my own dataset?

For example, I've found [this](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/notebooks/3_NeuralNetworks/convolutional_network.ipynb) IPython notebook which is pretty neat but it uses a pretrained model. I'd like to know how can I use this model for training my own set of data (images) and their corresponding labels.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You look at the model code or description to see what input it requires.  Then reformat your images to match that format.  Finally, feed your reformatted images to the model by whatever input means are specified.  I'm not sure just what all this entails, since you haven't shown your attempts so far, nor posted the salient details of the trained model.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.